# Formula IF with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare a cell value with a list of criteria using the length of each criteria and stop when the formula found a match

so my logical is, do a cycle to compare when the locked cell is empty then go out of the cycle and end the macro but if the cell contain a value enter to the cycle after that with variables generate a formula with a loop repeat the formula (increase the row every time the loop runs) until the formula result is a valid value not FALSE then go out of the cycle and offset down one row and start the cycle again with the second value looked and the same till finish the list of values i need to look.

so there is to list, one is the biggest one and there is another list of criteria.

```
C = 2
For i = 1 To Range("D1")
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Clean").Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
        For A = 2 To Range("I1")
        Do While (Sheets("Clean").Cells(C, 3)) = False
        Sheets("Clean").Cells(A, 3) = "=IF(LEFT(RC[-2],LEN(R&C&C10))=R&C&C10,RR&C&C10,FALSE)"
        Loop
        C = C + 1
        Next A
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This really needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: In this line are you expecting to use the value in I1? For A = 2 To Range("I1")

Comment: Yes , the value for the cycles are depending on the values that I will look for which for that i have created a count on cell "D1" and for the second which is the criterias to compare i have created a second count on cell "I1" so the second cycle must run no more than that count because those are the criterias to compare

Comment: so to be more especific, i have a big list of items on Column "A" that i have to add the family, the family is on colum "J" but some of the families are 2 digits length and other could be 3, 4 or more to 8 digits, so i want to create a cycle that come each cell on column A agains each criteria(family) based on the length on each family, so lets say that I have 87 families, each cell on column "A" must be compared 87 times till find the family that match(87 or less), column "J" is sorted "Z-A" based on the length.

Comment: i did this but only with 18criterias " IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$2))=$C$2,$C$2,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$3))=$C$3,$C$3,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$4))=$C$4,$C$4,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$5))=$C$5,$C$5,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$6))=$C$6,$C$6,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$7))=$C$7,$C$7,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$8))=$C$8,$C$8,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$9))=$C$9,$C$9,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$10))=$C$10,$C$10,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$11))=$C$11,$C$11,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$12))=$C$12,$C$12,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$13))=$C$13,$C$13,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$14))=$C$14,$C$14,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$15))=$C$15,$C$15,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$16))=$C$16,$C$16,IF(LEFT(A3,LEN($C$17))=$C$17,$C$17,IF(LEFT())))))))))))))))"

Comment: Solix you aren't getting any response for a couple of reasons: 1) People who comment don't automatically get notified when you type an answer - this is not a "forum". You need to "ping" them by preceding the username with @ - for example @mooseman. 2) Add additional information directly to the question, not in comments, by using the [edit] link below the question. Comments get removed and there's no formatting - so everything important needs to be *in the question*. 3) The first comment, about providing sample data and expected results, is very important.

Comment: Sorry about the long wait, but range("D1") is not the value in the cell you would need Range("D1)").value.  Hope this helps you learn VBA. But Tigeravatars answer seems to work, you should mark t as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based  on your description and comments, in cell C2 use this formula and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$88,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,$J$2:$J$88&"*"),),0)),"No matching family")
```

The `$J$2:$J$88` are your 87 families that you are trying to match the beginning of the column A cell against, adjust that range as necessary.

Comment: guuuuuau you are a master.....this is just a simple example of how far I am to know just a bit of excel, at the end i created the macro using VBA code   "  Sheets("Clean").Cells(A, 3) = "=IF(LEFT(RC[-2],LEN(R[" & x & "]C[7]))=R[" & x & "]C[7],R[" & x & "]C[7],False)""